# How to use range-based for() loop with std::map?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, dictionary

The common example for C++11 range-based for() loops is always something simple like this:

```
std::vector<int> numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
for ( auto xyz : numbers )
{
     std::cout << xyz << std::endl;
}
```

In which case `xyz` is an `int`.  But, what happens when we have something like a map?  What is the type of the variable in this example:

```
std::map< foo, bar > testing = { /*...blah...*/ };
for ( auto abc : testing )
{
    std::cout << abc << std::endl;         // ? should this give a foo? a bar?
    std::cout << abc->first << std::endl;  // ? or is abc an iterator?
}
```

When the container being traversed is something simple, it looks like range-based for() loops will give us each item, not an iterator.  Which is nice...if it was iterator, first thing we'd always have to do is to dereference it anyway.

But I'm confused as to what to expect when it comes to things like maps and multimaps.

(I'm still on g++ 4.4, while range-based loops are in g++ 4.6+, so I haven't had the chance to try it yet.)

Comment: The range for statement does an unholy dance with the standard library `std::begin` and `std::end` functions or member functions under the same name.

Comment: @will On a 3-line example, you're getting caught up on the fake variable name?

Answer (score 613, accepted):

Each element of the container is a `map<K, V>::value_type`, which is a `typedef` for `std::pair<const K, V>`.  Consequently, in C++17 or higher, you can write

```
for (auto& [key, value]: myMap) {
    std::cout << key << " has value " << value << std::endl;
}
```

or as

```
for (const auto& [key, value]: myMap) {
    std::cout << key << " has value " << value << std::endl;
}
```

if you don't plan on modifying the values.

In C++11 and C++14, you can use enhanced `for` loops to extract out each pair on its own, then manually extract the keys and values:

```
for (const auto& kv : myMap) {
    std::cout << kv.first << " has value " << kv.second << std::endl;
}
```

You could also consider marking the `kv` variable `const` if you want a read-only view of the values.

Comment: Related links I've found really helpful as I've studied this, in this order from most-to-least helpful: 1) [MOST EXCELLENT article] https://thispointer.com/how-to-iterate-over-an-unordered_map-in-c11/, 2) [EXCELLENT GENERAL INFO on iterators] https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/, 3) [cplusplus.com `std::unordered_map` reference pg] https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/, 4) [cppreference.com `std::unordered_map` reference pg] https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map, 5) see also [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66164132/4561887).

Comment: the last edit, adding `const` in the last code example, is unnecessary and does not fit with the author's original context. Also, it's not idiomatic to put `const` at that position every time. E.g., you should *not* use `const` if you want to modify the values or call the non-const method.

Comment: Also note that we can't use both `std::map<K, V>::value_type` and `std::pair<const K, V>` for structured binding declaration(e.g. `[key, value]`).

Answer (score 106):

In C++17 this is called [structured bindings](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0144r0.pdf), which allows for the following:

```
std::map< foo, bar > testing = { /*...blah...*/ };
for ( const auto& [ k, v ] : testing )
{
  std::cout << k << "=" << v << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Ist it possible to get a `const &` to the key, but a non-const reference to the value? (because that's what map::value_type does...)

Comment: @peterchen: `k` is `const` if you use `for(auto&[k,v]:testing)`

Comment: cpppreference on structured bindings http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding

Comment: If you're compiling with GCC you need version 7 or better for structured bindings: https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html

Answer (score 29):

From this paper: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2049.pdf

`for( type-speciﬁer-seq simple-declarator : expression ) statement`

is syntactically equivalent to

```
{
    typedef decltype(expression) C;
    auto&& rng(expression);
    for (auto begin(std::For<C>::begin(rng)), end(std::For<C>::end(rng)); begin != end; ++ begin) {
        type-speciﬁer-seq simple-declarator(*begin);
        statement
    }
}
```

So you can clearly see that what is `abc` in your case will be `std::pair<key_type, value_type >`. 
So for printing you can do access each element by `abc.first` and `abc.second`

Answer (score 16):

If you only want to see the keys/values from your map and like using boost, you can use the boost adaptors with the range based loops:

```
for (const auto& value : myMap | boost::adaptors::map_values)
{
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

there is an equivalent boost::adaptors::key_values

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/map_values.html

Answer (score 3):

If copy assignment operator of foo and bar is cheap (eg. int, char, pointer etc), you can do the following:

```
foo f; bar b;
BOOST_FOREACH(boost::tie(f,b),testing)
{
  cout << "Foo is " << f << " Bar is " << b;
}
```

Comment: First snippet of code is not using a "C++11 range-based for()". It is not an answer to "C++11: how to use range-based for() loop with std::map?"

Comment: @ytj It is already mentioned in the answer that it doesn't work. I don't want to remove that so that new users don't have to try it and find out the fact again.