# Can I easily iterate over the values of a map using a range-based for loop?

Tags: c++, dictionary, for-loop, c++11, key-value

Is it possible to iterate over all of the values in a `std::map` using just a "foreach"?

This is my current code:

```
std::map<float, MyClass*> foo ;

for (map<float, MyClass*>::iterator i = foo.begin() ; i != foo.end() ; i ++ ) {
    MyClass *j = i->second ;
    j->bar() ;
}
```

Is there a way I can do the following?

```
for (MyClass* i : /*magic here?*/) {
    i->bar() ;
}
```

Comment: Why you don't like i->second->bar() ?

Comment: Take a look at [this question's answer][1]. I think is exactly what you need.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963894/c11-how-to-use-range-based-for-loop-with-stdmap

Comment: @LyubomirVasilev: No, that one only asks how to iterate over a map in general for range-for. This one asks how to iterate specifically only over the values.

Comment: @Xeo Ahh, I see. I overlooked that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The magic lies with [Boost.Range's `map_values` adaptor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/map_values.html):

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/map.hpp>

for(auto&& i : foo | boost::adaptors::map_values){
  i->bar();
}
```

And it's officially called a "range-based for loop", not a "foreach loop". :)

Comment: i would have written `auto const&&`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I think you mean `auto const &&i` :)

Comment: @Xeo /ranged-based for loop/. I knew that. I must've been looking at SO tags too long… 6_9 Anyway, thank you! This is just what I was looking for. Can you explain why the pipe there is valid? That's a bitwise `or`, right?

Comment: @Blacklight: Boost.Range's adaptors overload the `operator|` to make chaining easier: `map | map_values | filtered(pred) | transformed(blub) | reversed`. :)

Comment: @Xeo `filtered()`? `transformed()`? `reversed`? Looks like I have a lot to read now… Good to know all of these exist!

Comment: @Blacklight: [It's all there in the documentation!](http://www.boost.org/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference.html) :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Doesn't `auto const&&` only bind to rvalue references specifically, while `auto&&` is a "universal" reference (can bind to lvalues as well)?

Comment: @Claudiu: Yes. My first comment has one ampersand too many, and my second has one too few. It appears that some commentary here has been removed, since the second comment evidently refers to something. Maybe the first one also referred to something. A lost context.

Answer (score 52):

From **C++1z/17**, you can use **structured bindings**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main() {
   std::map<int, std::string> m;

   m[1] = "first";
   m[2] = "second";
   m[3] = "third";

   for (const auto & [key, value] : m)
      std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: structured bindings are awesome, but I compile with -Werror and unused-variable cries about the key not being used a lot :)

Comment: Try `[[maybe_unused]]` attribute. See here https://stackoverflow.com/q/41404001/580083

Comment: @galois and @ Daniel, Sorry if this is a basic question but what exactly is ***Structured Bindings***? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @Milan Have you tried to google it? There are tons of explanations all around.

Comment: @DanielLangr I was reading an answer and as soon as I read a new word, I just commented here. But you are right... I should have googled it first. Sorry about that. (For the future readers: I found this short & simple video on *Structured Bindings* quite useful: https://youtu.be/eUsTO5BO3WI)

Answer (score 35):

```
std::map<float, MyClass*> foo;

for (const auto& any : foo) {
    MyClass *j = any.second;
    j->bar();
}
```

in c++11 (also known as c++0x), you can do this like in C# and Java

Comment: What do you mean by “you can do this”? Are you referring to ranged-based for loops in general?

Comment: YES! The new C++ Standard c++11 import a new for-range syntax feature,It's easier to iterator elments in containers.for example: vector<int> vec{0, 1, 2 ,3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};now in c++11,you can wirte code like this:                                                   for(auto any : vec) { cout << any << endl;}, you can compiler this code in visual c++ 2012, or in g++ 4.6 or higher with the argument -std=c++0x

Comment: Well…this is not quite helpful, as I knew about ranged-based loops before posting…my question, which @Xeo has already answered, is about how to iterate through just the values of a map, without a line like `MyClass *j = any.second ;` :P

Comment: I understand auto, but why const auto&? Is it not possible to edit the variable while in loop?

Answer (score 14):

Since [C++20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B20) you can add the range adaptor `std::views::values` from the [Ranges library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) to your [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). This way you can implement a similar solution to the one in [Xeo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13087074/2675154), but without using Boost:

```
#include <map>
#include <ranges>

std::map<float, MyClass*> foo;

for (auto const &i : foo | std::views::values)
    i->bar();
```

[Code on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MeElLXb01khCRnB9)

Comment: Even though I like the syntactic sugar of the "pipe" symbole here very much, the more obvious implementation would say

`for (auto const& it : std::views::values(foo)) it->bar();`

Comment: I agree, with only one range adapter, the better syntax is a matter of preference. But the idea is that you can chain multiple range adapters together, and then the piping concept makes more sense.