# structured binding with [[maybe_unused]]

Tags: c++, c++17, structured-bindings

Functional languages with pattern matching (sometimes?) have the possibility to ignore some bound values, but with C++17 structured bindings there seem to be no way to do that ([std::ignore with structured bindings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673080/stdignore-with-structured-bindings)). The advice is to use a dummy name, but then we'll get warnings about unused variables.

With the latest heads of both clang and gcc, this does the expected thing, which is nice and useful,

```
[[maybe_unused]] auto x =4 ; // fine, no warning
[[maybe_unused]] auto [a,dummyb,dummyc] = std::tuple<int,int,float>(1,1,1.0f);
```

but I would also have hoped this would work:

```
auto [g,[[maybe_unused]]dummyh,[[maybe_unused]]dymmyi] =
      std::tuple<int,int,float>(1,1,1.0f);
```

is there a specific reason [attributes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) can not be used here? (in the standard as well as technically). Neither gcc or clang accepts this.

---

Edit, collecting the support status: (thanks to [godbolt/compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/)). It works as expected in (could be earlier also):

- gcc 8.0 trunk (g++ 8.0.0 20171015 experimental)
- clang 4.0.0
- icc 18 (not tested, according to [specs](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/c17-features-supported-by-intel-c-compiler))
- msvc 19.22 (probably earlier) (Fixed, according to [bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/113023/maybe-unused-with-structured-binding-still-causes.html))

Try it out in godbolt at https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/H2duYd

Comment: I imagine that potentially blocking nested decompositions might have been a concern.

Comment: Hmm. Ok... `[g,[[possibly_unused]]]  = foo()`.. The more I think about it, the more I'm just fine with putting that single attribute on the outside :-)

Comment: Indeed requires gcc > 7.2 to make the attribute work.

Comment: So [[maybe_unused]] prevents the warning but then you also lose any checks for the return values you actually want to use.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In the structure bindings paper:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0144r2.pdf

they discuss their reasoning:

> 3.8 Should there be a way to explicitly ignore components?
>
> The motivation would be to silence compiler warnings about unused names.
>
> We think the answer should be “not yet.” This is not motivated by use
>   cases (silencing compiler warnings is a motivation, but it is not a
>   use case per se), and is best left until we can revisit this in the
>   context of a more general pattern matching proposal where this should
>   fall out as a special case.
>
> Symmetry with std::tie would suggest using
>   something like a std::ignore:
>
> ```
>    tuple<T1,T2,T3> f(); 
>    auto [x, std::ignore, z] = f(); // NOT proposed: ignore second element
> ```
>
> However, this feels awkward.
>
> Anticipating pattern matching in the language
>   could suggest a wildcard like _ or *, but since we do not yet have
>   pattern matching it is premature to pick a syntax that we know will be
>   compatible. This is a pure extension that can wait to be considered
>   with pattern matching.

Although this does not explicitly address `[[maybe_unused]]`, I assume the reasoning might be the same. Stopping compiler warnings is not a use-case.

Comment: If `maybe_unused` has a use case, then attaching `maybe_unused` to a variable that's declared in a structured binding has a use case. It's just another way of declaring a variable.

Comment: This still lacks reasoning on why attrubute syntax is not allowed. For example:
`for (auto& [x, y [[gnu::whatever]], z] = f() ) { .. }` . It doesn't matter what `gnu::whatever` might mean - the attribute syntax is open for future extensions. Not very useful would be the reasoning that the current available set of attributes in C++20 are unlikely to be used in this context.

Comment: @Ethouris At the time this question was asked, C++17 was still unpublished, so whether or not it was addressed in C++20 was not really a known thing when this answer was provided.

Comment: But even in C++20 the problem still doesn't seem to be solved, and I don't think the reasoning has changed. I'm using currently `for ([[maybe_unused]] auto& [x, y, z] = f() )`, which solves the problem of the warning, but hides the others. And the case when this is used isn't that rare - for example if you loop around the map, but you are not interested in the values of the keys.

Answer (score 14):

As a resolution to [CWG 2360](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2360), the working draft of the standard gained the following wording ([[dcl.attr.unused]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.attr.unused)):

> 2. The attribute may be applied to the declaration of a class, a *typedef-name*, a variable (including a structured binding declaration), a non-static data member, a function, an enumeration, or an enumerator.
> 3. For an entity marked `maybe_unused`, implementations should not emit a warning that the entity or its structured bindings (if any) are used or unused. For a structured binding declaration not marked `maybe_unused`, implementations should not emit such a warning unless all of its structured bindings are unused.

Structured binding declarations were previously not explicitly mentioned.