# Is it possible to mark one element of an unpacked tuple as unused

Tags: c++, c++17

This question is relevant to c++17 and above, which introduces the `[[maybe_unused]]` attribute.

I can apply `maybe_unused` to an entire unpacked tuple like so:

```
for ([[maybe_unused]] auto &[key, weak] : connection_cache_)
{
  if (auto locked = lock(weak); locked)
  {
    locked->cancel();
  }
}
```

However, marking the unused `key` does not work (at least on gcc-8):

```
for (auto &[ [[maybe_unused]] key, weak] : connection_cache_)
{
  if (auto locked = lock(weak); locked)
  {
    locked->cancel();
  }
}
```

This leaves me the choice of either not using the attribute or using a no-op to satisfy ensure no warnings when compiling with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` which is the norm for my codebase:

```
for (auto &[key, weak] : connection_cache_)
{
  boost::ignore_unused(key);
  if (auto locked = lock(weak); locked)
  {
    locked->cancel();
  }
}
```

Am I out of options?

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41404350/9593596)? I guess not a dupe, but relevant.

Comment: [Upgrade your compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/kvdm3T).

Comment: @PasserBy: your link doesn't use same flag as OP, and doesn't have attribute neither.

Comment: @Jarod42 Oops, but the warning is in -Wall. I'm demonstrating newer gcc only issues unused warnings if none of the bindings were used.

Comment: @PasserBy: Even gcc-8.1 don't issue warning. but warning might be legit...

Comment: Thanks everyone for comments. I have accepted that the question as a dupe. Short answer is "yes, you're out of options".

Comment: Makes you want to switch to Go and have `_` huh?

Comment: @PasserBy there's a lot about c++ that I like. I'd prefer if the standard release cycle was quarterly so we could have more nice things more often...