# How to mark unused one of multiple values in C++ using structured bindings?

Tags: c++, c++17, compiler-warnings, structured-bindings

In C++17, I have a function returning multiple values via a std::tuple and structured bindings and I wish to ignore one of the return values and suppress any warnings related to that.

I tried the following which does not compile:

```
[const auto [outside, [[maybe_unused]] edge, inside] = Classify();

   => error: expected identifier before '[' token
```

I also tried this:

```
[[maybe_unused]] const auto [outside, edge, inside] = Classify();

   => warning: unused variable 'edge' [-Wunused-variable]
```

Neither works as desired with GCC v7.3.0.

Is there a way in C++17 to neatly specify that `edge` is unused in a multiple value return syntax using structured bindings or is this missing from the current language definition?

Comment: `(void)edge;` Note that gcc 8+ doesn't warn on unused bindings at all. [Relevent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41404001/2069064) (though probably not dupe).

Comment: Warnings are not part of the language, really.  GCC >=8 does not warn even in C++17 mode with no attribute, so long as at least one of the bindings is used.

Comment: As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404001/structured-binding-with-maybe-unused/55218762#55218762), this was deemed a defect in the standard, the resolution of which implied the GCC 8+ behaviour.