# Disable warning for unused structured bindings

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, unused-variables, structured-bindings

I'm extracting a tuple with `auto [...]` but I'm only using **some** of the tuple coordinates.
I wanted to know if there is some elegant way to avoid the `unused-variable` compiler warning?
Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::vector<std::tuple<char,float,int>> myvec;
    myvec.push_back(std::make_tuple('a',3.5,8));
    myvec.push_back(std::make_tuple('b',1.5,4));
    auto [c,f,_] = myvec[1];
    std::cout << "char float is " << c << " " << f << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the compilation line + warning:

```
$ g++ -Wall -std=c++17 main.cpp -o main
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:10:13: warning: unused variable ‘_’ [-Wunused-variable]
  auto [c,f,_] = myvec[1];
             ^
```

(I used a Haskell-like variable `_` to self document the fact that the last int is a don't-care value).

Comment: Self documentation is a good idea, but using `_` is problematic. Use `ignored` for the same noble purpose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [structured binding with \[\[maybe\_unused\]\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404001/structured-binding-with-maybe-unused)

Comment: Why not just extract elements of interest one by one without structed bindings? Note that in general case creating an unused variable may lead to overhead.

Comment: C++20 recommends that implementations *should* not emit a warning if any of the variables is used.

Comment: I would also like to know your `g++ --version`.

Comment: @Yunnosch I pasted the exact and entire compiler message. it only complains about the unused `_`. I'm using `gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0`

Comment: [[maybe_unused]] did not solve my problem. What `g++` version is needed for this?