# How can ignore some elements of tuple?

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17

I have a tuple with some elements, and I want to assign some elements of  tuple to variables, and ignore some of them.

```
 auto tuple1 = std::make_tuple(1,2,3,4);
 // variable a should be placeholder 1 in tuple and variable b should be place holder 3;
 int a,b ;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use from std::tie and std::ignore in tuple such as :

```
 int a, b;
 tie(std::ignore, a, std::ignore, b)= tuple1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [strutural binding along](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) with C++20 support, you could write

```
#include <tuple>    

auto tuple1 = std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3, 4);
[[maybe_unused]] auto [dummy1, a, dummy2, b] = tuple1;
```

Use only `a` and `b`. The `[[maybe_unused]]`  part is to suppres the warning due to `-Wunused-variable`.

This is actually inspired from the answer: [structured binding with [[maybe_unused]]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404001/structured-binding-with-maybe-unused?noredirect=1&lq=1)