# Inspecting the content of a map while debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, dictionary, unordered-map

For debugging, I need to see the content of a map (`std::unordered_map` or `std::map`), which the Eclipse CDT debugger does not give me in a readable form, e.g. `{1: 2, 3:4, ...}`

What is the best way to inspect the content of a map while debugging?

Do I have to go back to debugging with print-statements? If yes, how would a concise macro or function look like that prints the content of any map as a string?

Comment: The debugger in Eclipse is GDB, do e.g. a Google search for adding types to GDB.

Comment: does not give me useful results which I can understand: http://bit.ly/T1XXYs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to go back to debugging with print-statements? If yes, how would a concise macro or function look like that prints the content of any map as a string?

I don't know if you do or not - I don't use Eclipse, but printing a map is very easy:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::map<K, V>& m)
{
    os << "{ ";
    for (typename std::map<K, V>::const_iterator i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); ++i)
    {
        if (i != m.begin()) os << ", ";
        os << i->first << ": " << i->second;
    }
    return os << " }";
}
```

Then you can just use `<< my_map`.  Note though that in a large code base there's a chance that someone else will have had the same "bright" idea, so you might want to put your helper function in your own namespace, or give it a more localised name.  Things like the choice of surrounding `"{ "` and `" }"` and `", "` separators are arbitrary and may not suit all users - some may want automatic string quoting/escaping etc., so putting this in a global namespace would be dubious at the best of times, and in this case it might even be reserved for possible inclusion in a future C++ Standard or something - after all, it's kind of liking adding your own names into the `std::` namespace.  Check the Standard if you care.

Comment: This would be a solution, but when I compile this code I get the error: `/usr/local/Cellar/log4cxx/0.10.0/include/log4cxx/helpers/messagebuffer.h:190:47: error: cannot bind 'std::basic_ostream<char>' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'`

Comment: It's even simpler with [C++11 range based for loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), as shown for example in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6963910/440558).

Comment: @cls: you're not getting a match on this template, and that error's coming from another candidate function.  If you put this in a different namespace from the calling code, then it won't be found.  You could add `using Whatever_Namespace_It_Is_In::operator<<;` before the code that wants to use it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Seeing `m.begin()` in the loop control and separator test has a nice consistency; given C++11 I'd just simplify `typename std::map<K, V>::const_iterator` to `auto`.  With ranged based for, what would you recommend - `&kv != &*m.begin()`, or a separate `bool first = true; ... if (first) first = false; else os << ", "` / `size_t i = 0; ... if (i++)`?

Answer (score 1):

GDB can be [extended](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Extending-GDB.html#Extending-GDB) with [Python](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python.html), and there is an API for [pretty printing](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Pretty-Printing-API.html).

There are [many pretty printers for C++ available](https://www.google.com/search?q=gdb+python+pretty+print&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=O5t&tbo=d&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3Aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=gdb+python+pretty+print+c%2B%2B&oq=gdb+python+pretty+print+c%2B%2B&gs_l=serp.3...199791.200254.0.200467.4.4.0.0.0.0.116.314.3j1.4.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.-1RvSW2nR_o&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355325884,d.bGE&fp=33d9d6dbf12ca4df&bpcl=39967673&biw=1918&bih=977), like for example [this one](http://lumiera.org/documentation/technical/howto/DebugGdbPretty.html).

Comment: This would be the optimal solution. I'd like to try this, but I cannot get a python-enabled gdb to run in Eclipse (see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913818/how-to-get-a-codesigned-gdb-on-osx)