# MAC OS X 10.8.5 gdb codesigned

Tags: c, macos, unix, gdb

I trying to use the GDB debugger on OS X 10.8.5 to step through an example from the OS X Internals text book however gdb reports:

Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 2930: (os/kernel) failure(0x5)
(Please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8)).

What does the following mean? Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 2930.
What is taskgated? 
I do not want to use lldb yet, so how can I utilize gdb without elevating to the root user via sudo gdb?

[image: screen shot of the error prompt]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913818/how-to-get-a-codesigned-gdb-on-osx/

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thanks for the pointer. I have researched this issue significantly and can not find a solution that works except execution gdb as root. I would rather not elevate gdb privilege as I'm not aware of the adverse affects.