# Gnat Programming Studio: Install gdb version 8.0.1 in parallel with GPS 2018 to sign gdb code. Experiences?

Tags: gdb, ada, gnat-gps

I'm having trouble using gdb (Debugger) on MacOS High Sierra. With the help of

- [How to get a "codesigned" gdb on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913818/how-to-get-a-codesigned-gdb-on-osx)
- [gdb doesn't work on macos High Sierra 10.13.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001329/gdb-doesnt-work-on-macos-high-sierra-10-13-3)

and several others (thanks!!) I have already collected the information required to fix the problem:

- The basic problem is that you have to sign the code with a certificate.
- I already created a certificate
- The gdb I'm currently using is 7.10. This version will **not** work, according to the sources, but it is not mentioned, why. The latest gdb version 8.1 is **not** working because of a bug, so version 8.0.1 is recommended.

I'm using Gnat Programming System (GNAT Community edition 2018 downloaded from AdaCore). The gdb version included in that package is 7.10.

**Here is my specific problem:** Before I even try myself, does anybody have experiences installing the gdb 8.0.1 in parallel with the GPS package? (Please note that I already had some trouble mixing GPS with separately installed gnat packages on my Linux System).

Or alternatively: Why does the gdb 7.10 version not work? To give it a try, I made the attempt to sign this version, but got the error message: "Already signed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a definitive answer here! But .. running on 10.13.5 under `sudo`, to avoid code-signing issues (while admittedly running a slight risk),

- The CE2018 edition starts the program but hangs,
- GDB 8.1 built with GCC 8.1.0 crashes (I found a [patch](https://github.com/saagarjha/binutils-gdb/commit/760d3f1539d52a0d52e43998cc951a0ee75bd606), but after applying it GDB failed, although less spectacularly),
- The GNAT GPL 2017 edition rebuilt with GCC 8.1.0 hangs,
- The GNAT GPL 2017 edition as downloaded works OK.

It *might* be possible to replace the CE2018 gdb with the GPL2017 version, code-signed of course, though there’s a raft of support code (in e.g. `$prefix/share/gdb`) that might not match too well. Worth a try.

An alternative to replacing might be to delete (or rename) the CE2018 `$prefix/bin/gdb` and arrange to have the GPL2017 suite on `PATH` after the CE2018 suite.

---

PS: I code-signed the CE2018 gdb and it worked OK! Colour me baffled.

There were several lines of reports on the lines of

```
warning: `/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Binaries/Libc_darwin/install/TempContent/Objects/Libc.build/libsystem_darwin.dylib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/darwin_vers.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
```

which are annoying but seem harmless. I’ve not seen this with the GPL2017 edition.

Comment: After consulting the meta on etiquette, I decided to comment that I will not be able to try out your advice about signing the library before two weeks or so, so don’t wonder I did not react immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay in reacting to your answer.

Eventually, I was able to sign the gdb. After installing the CE2018 version, trying to sign the gdb of that package, gave different and better error messages than the 2017 version. Here some details:

- Switch user (su) to become admin
- use sudo code sign -f -s
- restart the computer!
- After starting the debugger (in GPS), I had to authorise "developer tool access" with admin password.

Running the debugger, I also get the same error messages you described. There was no need to add anything to the .gdbinit file (as described in some other guidlines)