# Direction of for loop based on variable

Tags: c++

I have a couple of biggish for loops which I would like to separate into functions to reduce code duplication.

The only difference between them is the first line of the loop.

One is:

```
for (int j = 50; j < average_diff; j++) {
```

The other is:

```
for (int j = upper_limit; j > lower_limit; j--) {
```

I have an integer, tb which indicates which one I'd like to use (it has a value of 1 or 2 respectively).

I'm wondering how I might best accomplish this. Is this a good use case for macros?

Comment: `if (cond) { for (first; loop; etc) { function(); } } else { for (second; loop; etc) { function(); } }`

Comment: You might want to extract the loop's body into a function. Or, if possible, change the second loop to `for (int j = lower_limit+1; j <= upper_limit; j++)`. Then you can extract the whole loop to the function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't wrap the `for`, just wrap the contents in a function:

```
for (int j = 50; j < average_diff; j++) {
   process(j);
}

for (int j = upper_limit; j > lower_limit; j--) {
   process(j);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

No, doesn't sound like a good case for macros at all.

The best (most C++-ish) thing would probably be to use a [range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963894/c11-how-to-use-range-based-for-loop-with-stdmap), and pass that to the function.

Answer (score 1):

If your variable is, like you say, `1` for one direction and `2` for another, you can use the [ternary operator `?:`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#C.2B.2B):

```
for (int i = (dir == 1 ? 0 : 20);
     dir == 1 ? i < upper_limit :
                i > lower_limit;
     i += (dir == 1 ? 1 : -1))
{
    ...
}
```

However, it might be more readable if you just use a simple `if` statement:

```
if (dir == 1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < upper_limit; i++)
    {
    }
}
else
{
    for (int i = 20; i > lower_limit; i--)
    {
    }
}
```

If you go with the last, then I suggest you put the code inside the loop in a separate function that you call, so you don't have any duplicate code.