# Where does unordered_map<K, V>::iterator come from?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

When I'm using a `std::unordered_map<K, V>` I know that the iterator to each key-value pair is of type `std::unordered_map<K, V>::iterator`. I also know that the iterator itself points to a `pair<const K, V>`. However, the only reason I know the iterator points to a pair is from looking at example code. Where is this behavior defined?

For example, if I go to [the documentation at cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), I don't see where this behavior is explained. It only says that the member `iterator` is defined as a `ForwardIterator`.

So, my question is, how would a smart developer know what a `std::unordered_map<K, V>::iterator` actually represents? I'm sure there is some logical leap I'm missing.

Comment: That mention of [`ForwardIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator) is a clickable link. Of further interest: "`std::unordered_map` meets the requirements of `Container`, `AllocatorAwareContainer`, `UnorderedAssociativeContainer`." Each of these camel-case identifiers are also links, with further information about how a container is expected to behave.

Comment: cppreference.com is a public wiki. Please go fix that page and make it clearer. I'll do the same.

Comment: Done. I edited the page and added an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66164132/4561887. Hopefully the edit sticks. If not, use the cplusplus.com reference page instead (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/) as it makes it _crystal clear_ when it says an `iterator` is: `a forward iterator to value_type` and  a `const_iterator` is `a forward iterator to const value_type`, and is shows the `value_type` to be `pair<const key_type,mapped_type>`.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963894/how-to-use-range-based-for-loop-with-stdmap/6963910#6963910.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For STL containers

objects of type `iterator` when de-referenced return an object of type `reference`, which is a reference to an object of type `value_type`.

These are all defined inside the `container`.

Note the std::map is defined as a container. This information is part of this documentation.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container

Comment: That cppreference page is now deleted.

Comment: @GabrielStaples Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

> So, my question is, how would a smart developer know what a `std::unordered_map<K, V>::iterator` actually represents? I'm sure there is some logical leap I'm missing.

As of a few minutes ago, this page (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) now shows the image below.

Notice the sections I highlighted. It now makes it crystal clear that an `iterator` is "to `value_type`", and a `const iterator` is "to `const value_type`". And `value_type` is specified as `std::pair<const Key, T>`. So, dereferencing an interator (`*my_iterator`) provides you an object of type `value_type`, which is `std::pair<const Key, T>` in this case--for a `std::unordered_map`. This should make it all clear now.

[image]

### References:

Related links I've found really helpful as I've studied this, in this order from most-to-least helpful:

1. [MOST EXCELLENT article] https://thispointer.com/how-to-iterate-over-an-unordered_map-in-c11/
2. [EXCELLENT GENERAL INFO on iterators] https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/
3. [cplusplus.com `std::unordered_map` reference pg] https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/
4. [cppreference.com `std::unordered_map` reference pg] https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map

### See also:

1. [How to use range-based for() loop with std::map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963894/how-to-use-range-based-for-loop-with-stdmap/6963910#6963910)