# map auto-based loop single element access C++

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, stdmap, auto

I'm trying to understand the "theory" besides the `auto` loop over

> std::map

elements in C++.
I have a `std::map` with a `std::string` as KEY and a `vector<std:string>` as VALUE. I can access its elements with:

```
for ( auto &element : myMap ) {
    std::cout << element.first << ": " << '\t';
    for ( std::string subElement : element.second ) std::cout << subElement << ", ";
  }
}
```

as for the loop over the `vector<string>` elements I know that I could put "auto" instead of "std::string". But what would be the equivalent for the map in such case? I studied and searched around and I found in [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963894/how-to-use-range-based-for-loop-with-stdmap) that each map element is accessed as a

> map< K, V>::value_type

but how would I write it down? I tried:

```
for ( std::map<std::string, vector<std::string>> &pz : myMap ) {
    // print ...
}
```

and similars, but they just does not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`std::map::value_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is defined as the type of `std::map`'s element, which is `std::pair<const Key, T>` (i.e. `std::pair<const std::string, vector<std::string>>` here).  You should use it as

```
for ( std::map<std::string, vector<std::string>>::value_type &pz : myMap ) {
    //                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // print ...
}
```

Comment: it was that intuitive...so indicatively "::value_type" make C++ interpret it as a "single element" of which access the subelements?

Comment: @cccnrc Yes, and the element of `std::map` is `std::pair` indeed.

Comment: @cccnrc `std::map` is a map. `std::map::value_type` is a member type of the `std::map` class, and as its name suggests, it is the type of a value in the map.

Comment: @cccnrc It's a bit confusing since a map contains _key-value_ pairs, but `value_type` is not a type of stored _values_, but a type of whole entries (key-value pairs). The type of values is spelled as `mapped_type`.

Comment: Perhaps use `reference` instead of `value_type &` though…

Comment: don't we need `typename` as `value_type` is dependent to the `std::pair<const Key, T>`?

Comment: @UsingCpp For `std::map<std::string, vector<std::string>>`, `typename` is not required; all the template arguments have been determined.

Answer (score 0):

songyuanyao has answered your question.
One thing needed to be clarified here is that `std::map` is defined as

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class map;
```

The class name should be `std::map<key type, value type>`.

Comment: it is actually `std::map<const key type, value type>`